# Control Multiple Universal Robotic arm in ros2

Tags: ros, ros2, moveit, hardware-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am just wondering what is the best approach to control multiple universal  robotics arms from moveit and ros2. both robotic arms share their workspace so with collision avoidance.

If anyone had previous experience please share

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409355/control-multiple-universal-robotic-arm-in-ros2/) by [Osal22](https://answers.ros.org/users/66668/osal22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2022-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a tutorial for that:  https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/examples/dual_arms/dual_arms_tutorial.html

One of the limitations of the tutorial setup is that motion planning & execution for the 2 arms will be synchronous. Basically, that's because the MoveGroupInterface is single-threaded.

They do share a planning scene so collision avoidance should work as you expect.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2022-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Osal22](https://answers.ros.org/users/66668/osal22/) on 2022-11-14**:
Thank you it is helpful. but if I want to control both arm simultaneously with different goals and with collision avoidance

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2022-11-14**:
You can do this, no problem:

```
I want to control both arm simultaneously with different goals and with collision avoidance
```

But not something like this:

```
Plan a motion for Arm 1
Begin executing for Arm 1
Plan a motion for Arm 2
Begin executing for Arm 2
Arm 1 motion completes
Arm 2 motion completes
```